# How to connect my local SQL Server to our MOSS 2007 site so I can invoke it in my Sharepoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have asked our IT to do it but couldn't do it right away. Is this a difficult procedure for MOSS 2007 admins? I'm curious about the step by step process to accomplish adding other database connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found a solution to connect to database using SPD 2007, the secret was to avoid what they call “double hop” between machines on a network. This is resolved by using MOSS 2007 SSO (Single Sign-On) whereby it results to just “one hop” during database calls to web servers.

The SSO needs to be mapped by configuring the Application Definition which only server administrators can create and modify, using the browser-based Central Admin UI.

Can you help set this up using Central Admin UI please? Step by step process is described on this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/08/27/an-introduction-to-single-sign-on-sso-with-data-views.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments

With Single Sign-On, you can connect to an external database, even if it doesn't reside on the same server as your SharePoint site.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-database-as-a-data-source-HA010100908.aspx#BM4